# Doing basic math in Rails within each "each do" loop and getting the sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, view, model

New to Rails! I have products which are associated to a campaign. Each @product has a .price and .orders_count associated to it.

What I wanted to do is multiply the .price with .orders_count for each @product, and add them all up to get a total cost for the @campaign.

Being new to Rails, wasn't sure how to do the write syntax and had the following in the view. This does the first piece, but does not add them all up at the end. Thanks for the help!

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
    <% if p.orders_count? %>
        <%= (number_to_currency((p.price) * p.orders_count)) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Don't do it in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a variable to keep track of the sum of all products, and add the product to it each time through the loop. Try this:

```
<% sum = 0 %>
<% @products.each do |p| %>
    <% if p.orders_count? %>
        <% product = (number_to_currency((p.price) * p.orders_count)) %>
        <% sum += product %>
        <%= product %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

The sum is: <%= sum %>
```

Comment: this is great! i have a remaining issues where the p.price is $9.99 for example and doesn't want to work unless converted over to a proper number. i know number_to_current(p.price) will turn a value into money, but whats the helper to turn it into a decimal number?

Comment: I did this, is this ideal? <%= number_to_currency(sum/100.00) %>

Comment: [number_to_precision](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) is the method you're looking for. Generally you'll want to perform your logic outside of the view, but for this purpose it is completely okay IMO.

Comment: great thoughts. i appreciate it!